# Knockout protected observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to use the protected observable in my code and so I found this tutorial:

[HERE](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html)

While playing with the demo on the website, I found the following scenario:

- Click an edit button for a particular row, and then change the value of an input field but  DO NOT click the accept button.
- Then go to another row and click it's edit button.
- Then come back to the row in which you changed one of the input field values, click edit, then click accept. You will find that the value you initially changed will get saved.

I believe that this will confuse the end user because when you initially changed the value, that value DID NOT appear on the screen after you clicked on edit button of another row. The value shown on screen was still the original value.

So, how do you go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the protected observable but how the demo handles the edit button.

To make it work for your scenario in the `editItem` you need cancel any pending edit before start editing the new row:

```
this.editItem = function(item) {
    if (self.selectedItem() != null)
        self.cancelItemEdit()
    self.selectedItem(item);
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smqenmt1/).